# For squarefree $i$ what is $\sum_1^{n} \frac{1}{i}$?

Tags: number-theory, summation, square-numbers

For squarefree $i$ what is $\sum_1^{n} \frac{1}{i}$ ? I use $\sum_{\sqrt{n}>m>1} \mu(m)  ln(\frac{n}{m^2}+\frac{1}{2})$. I know about the connection with $\zeta(2)$ and $\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}$ but that does not help ??

Can I do better ?

Comment: This is a suggestion
rather than a solution.

Since
$\sum_{1 \le i \le n} 1/i
\approx \ln n$,
I would guess that
your sum is about
$\zeta(2) \ln(n)$.

The term "logarithmic mean"
comes to mind, also.

Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: @marty cohen: Wouldn't the sum in the post be *less* than $\sum 1/n$? I think $\sum_{p\leq x}1/p < \sum_{i\leq x} 1/i < \sum_{n \leq x} 1/n $ but maybe I haven't had enough coffee. Your suggestion implies the sum is larger?

Comment: Yes daniel and marty , the ratio is asymptoticly $\zeta(2)$ but it is indeed $\frac{ln(n)}{\zeta(2)}$. This is easy to prove. But this does not answer my question(s). It is merely the " connection " to $\zeta(2)$ that I mentioned.